# How to configure "Hover Image Preview" package of sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

I just Installed this package https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Hover%20Image%20Preview with package control in sublime text 3

now I want to configure it as said in the link, can anyone tell from where I can configure the width and height???

this package do not show up in Preferences>Package Setting

THANKS...

Answer (score 0):

I've been there, it took me a while until I fully realized how Sublime settings work and being changed.

### A general suggestion that might help with this issue (and many other you might encounter while working with Sublime):

Read [this page](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html) carefully, esp. **SETTINGS FILES** section, pay special attention to the hierarchy of the prefs files.

For me it was a true revelation that set thing straight for good.

Hope it helps you too

Comment: didnt help in my case, I only want to change setting of one package which I mentioned above